# Is there a way to hide the .php file extension with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was wondering if there was a way to hide the `.php` file extension with .htaccess.

I've seen quite a few websites do this, for example facebook on most of its pages does not show the `.php` file extension.

For example I want all my url's to be:

> https://mywebsite.com/about

instead of

> https://mywebsite.com/about.php

**EDIT**

Inside my `.htaccess` file I have the following code already:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Do I just append

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

at the end of the file? Or how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

This code is currently working in my pc.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

It will remove extension **.php** from URL and set remaining URL as it is.

- Thanks

Answer (score 2):

your have to active the rewrite_mod

and in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

While this has been answered a few times already, a quick search will show you results like this that should work:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: I edited my post, perhaps you could indicate how can I do it? Since I'm getting an internal error code 500.

Comment: you should only need to enable RewriteEngine once, not sure that should cause a 500 error though

Answer (score 1):

add the following to the .htaccess file (make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled)

```
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
Options Multiviews
```

and let mod_negotiation take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Second line explanation:

```
^ Start of line
(  Capture everything enclosed (start)
. Any single character
* Zero or more of any character
) Capture everything enclosed (end)
$ End of line
$1.php Get the captured match and append .php, there's the rewrite!
```

Voila!

```
hello => hello.php
home => home.php
```

Comment: I already have 

    `RewriteEngine on`
    `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
    `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Do I just append that code at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0):

by the way ,if you are not familiar with `.htaccess` syntax,

you can try this **[htaccess rule generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)** for generate rules